# how to upload file in php and move file to a special folder

Tags: php

I want to upload users sent files to a corresponding folder. This is my code. It does not upload to where I want.

```
$type=$_POST["type"];
$username_post=$_POST["username"];
$text=$_POST["text"];
$image=basename($_POST["image"]);
$page_number=$_POST["page_number"];
$video=basename($_POST["video"]);
$voice=basename($_POST["voice"]);
$title=$_POST["title"];
$dir=$username_post;
if( is_dir($dir) === false )
  {
       mkdir($dir,0666, true);
       mkdir($dir.'/'.$title,0666, true);
  }
  else
  {
      mkdir($dir.'/'.$title,0666, true);
      }

  if( is_dir($dir.'/'.$title) === true )
    {   
    $uploads_dir =$dir.'/'.$title;  
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$uploads_dir.'/'.$name);
  }
```

Comment: What error you getting? Have you checked $_FILES?

Comment: You should protect your code to avoid injection (sanitize everything that is given by a user, in this case the $title).

Comment: Please, read about it before you post a question. For example [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) made a nice tutorial suitable for beginners. You didn't provide us with enough details  for someone to be actually able to help you.

Comment: yes,when i writ static path upload is success.but i want upload dynamic.for each user create ane folder and with each title create one folder in it

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you shouldn't create the directory from a user input post value.
   Ex : if user enters some disallowed characters like "/*|" in your     $_POST['username'], then you won't be able to create a directory with these values.
   Check if you have permission to create directory in that folder.
2. Second check the $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 or not. if not 0 that file has an error and can not be uploaded.
3. Use a "else condition" for last "if statement" to see if the "if statement" executes or not.
4. And also check if u have mentioned enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag.